# Own Emoji Keyboard - Listing all unicode Emojis

Tags: unicode, fonts, keyboard, emoji

i want to create an own emoji-keyboard for an universal app. I need this for the reason of usage on desktop.

So i searched a lot but didnt found something helpfull. I want to show up all possible Emojis.

But i dont really want to use a file or something where i have to manage all the unicodes of the emojis - i want something like an Enumeration (like Symbols in c#)

Is there something like that? I also searched for a method of listing all keys of a font or something what would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all official unicode characters in the latest database from unicode.org (http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/). The file UnicodeData.txt contains all unicode characters including their names and properties.
Unfortunately, the file is not an c++ or c# enumeration but only a text file, so you have to write your own parser for this (but the file format can be easily parsed and is documented).

Comment: Sorry, no, i don't think so. But parsing of the original unicode data file should be not too hard.